# How do you test a jQuery plugin if all methods are private?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Here is an example of a simple jQuery plugin:

*it takes an element and if it is a div sets a width*

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
  var pluginName= 'changeDivWidth',
      defaults = {
        width: '50%'
      };

  function Plugin (element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {
      if(this.isDiv()) {
        this.changeWidth();
      }
    },
    isDiv: function () {
      if (this.element.nodeName === 'DIV') {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    },
    changeWidth: functioon () {
      $(this.element).css('width', this.options.width);
    }
  };

  $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
        $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
      }
    });
  };
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

How would I test this jQuery plugin?

My first reaction would be that I want to unit test each method of `Plugin.prototype`, but these are private and "you're not supposed to test private methods". So my only other option that I can see would be to run a bunch of integration tests where the plugin is called in different situations and see what the output is.

So say I want to test my two privte methods:

```
describe('changeDivWidth', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    loadFixtures('myFixtures.html');
  });

  it('should not change width of non-DIV elements', function () {
    var span = $('span').changeDivWidth({width: '30px'}).get(0);
    expect($(span).width()).not.toBe(30);
  });

  it('should change width of DIV elements', function () {
    var div = $('div').changeDivWidth({width: '30px'}).get(0);
    expect($(div).width()).toBe(30);
  });

});
```

Great, this seems to work... Except, if `Plugin.prototype.isDiv` fails in such a way that it always returns false then the test for `Plugin.prototype.changeWidth` will also fail. So now I have one failing method but two failing tests, meaning I don't know where the issue is. Obviously on something this small it's no big deal, but on a larger project I can see this becoming a pain.

So am I missing something here? Is there a better way to be testing this?

I suppose I could order my tests to run in the same order as the methods they are testing, but as the project grows in complexity I could see this being a pain to maintain.

Sorry for the long winded question. I wasn't sure how to ask it without examples.

P.S. I know my tests don't really hold up, they are just supposed to be an oversimplified example.

Comment: Could you provide some reading about "you're not supposed to test private methods"? I haven't heard that.

Comment: I've seen this all over the web, it seems to be the general concensus. Although I have seen arguments against it too. It'll take a little work to find specific examples. Give me a few.

Comment: Here is an article I just found that supports the "you're not supposed to test private methods" philosophy. http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/05/31/my-take-on-unit-testing-private-methods

Comment: I suppose that the answer could be just testing the private methods, but what would the best way be in that case? The way I'm most familiar with, where you expose the method in a public testing object which is then removed during the build process, just doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: This question seems more suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In fact, see this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/100959/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods

Comment: Simplification: `isDiv: function () {return this.element.nodeName === 'DIV'}`

Comment: @jfriend00 The question isn't about the specific code.

Comment: @moss - I know it's not the question you're asking - that's why this was a side comment.  Not sure why you got defensive.  Excuse me for making a simplifying suggestion.  Still not sure why you write an `if/else` when you can just return the value of the comparision.  Oh well - your code - do what you like.  I thought the suggestion might be useful.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wasn't being defensive... maybe my response was too short which made it seem that way. I simply meant that because the question is not about the code that a small syntactical change like that would not really add to the question. Perhaps you were thinking this was code I am actually using rather than just example code intended to make a point? Either way, thank you for the suggestion. You are correct, that would be a better way to write it.

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago Wow, I didn't even know about programmers.stackexchange.com. Thanks for pointing me there. I'm not really sure what would make this more suitable there than on stackoverflow. Could you explain?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour "Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for ... getting expert answers on *conceptual questions* about software development."

Comment: Hmmmm, well if any moderators feel like moving this over there(possible?) feel free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, don't test the private methods. You should be testing against the public interface to make sure that it works as it should, and not worry about the internals because they should be able to change freely because they are private.

On the point of small projects versus big ones: As projects become bigger, components within them should be broken up for the code to stay maintainable. Therefore, functions such as isDiv would probably be put into a utility class/object that can be used in many objects instead of having many copies of it in many different classes. When it is separated out like this, the function will be exposed in a public interface and therefore be testable.

See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/100959/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods

Comment: But even if it is broken up it doesn't change that the whole thing is wrapped in a self executing function. So any new utility function will still be private just like the constructor in the example is private. Or...?

Comment: Your plugin manipulates the DOM, which is still something that can be tested!

Comment: So you're saying that the example I gave in the question would be the right approach?